# What are the Malloc memory leaks shown in Instruments in Xcode, and how can I fix them?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I recently started working on optimizing the memory usage in my Swift application. When I started using the Leaks Instrument, I got over 100 "Malloc" leaks with no descriptions. I've looked around, but cannot find an explanation.

I'm running iOS 12.0 and Xcode 10.2

I went as far as commenting out all of the functions that were being called in my ViewDidLoad, and I'm still getting around 50 Malloc leaks. 
I researched what causes memory leaks, and there's nothing in my code to suggest a leak, but I'm fairly new to memory management.

It's important for my app to not have leaks, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You would need to provide some of your relevant code in order for us to help you diagnose your unfortunate situation.

Comment: That's the thing, I have all of my code commented out. I have a tab bar controller with three tabs on the bottom. Each one of the tabs has a View Controller assigned to it, but all of the code in the View Did Load for each controller is commented out.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a very simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int mem(long int mem) {
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * mem);
    if(buffer == NULL) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    long int mem_to_alloc = 2;
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++, mem_to_alloc *= 2) {
        printf("Allocation: %d Allocating: %ld\n", i, mem_to_alloc);
        if( mem(mem_to_alloc) == 1 )
          break;
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

First of all, make sure to set proper configuration in `Build Scheme`

[image]

Once in `Instruments` choose `Leaks`

[image]

After you have run your code, you should see suspicious allocations with the calls stack (`Stack Trace`) on the right.

[image]